# New-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Failed to enumerate SSL bindings, error code 234

Tags: iis, ssl, powershell-3.0

PowerShell V3.0

I am trying to associate SSL Certificate to my website in IIS.

below is the command i am executing

```
New-WebBinding -Name "name" -IP $ipAddress -Port $port -Protocol $protocol -HostHeader $hostName
$sslBinding = Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -eq "CN=*.domain.com, OU=Domain Control Validated" } | select -First 1
$sslBinding | New-Item IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443
```

Error details

> New-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet.
>   Failed to enumerate SSL bindings, error  code 234. At
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\2\82dc23c5-6699-4e69-a4dc-ca9b1f65a1d5.ps1:17
>   char:15
>   + $sslBinding | New-Item IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443
>   +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand